# Installed package in project and getting error

Tags: python-2.7, python-import

I have install package in my personal folder

```
sudo pip install boto3 -t ./lib
```

boto3 install in lib folder

```
Project 
 --> lib 
     --> boto3 package
     --> __init__.py
 --> python script
   --> read.py
```

lib has one package boto3

Now i am accessing boto3 in python script read.py
    import lib.boto3

```
Getting error 
  File "read.py", line 5, in <module>
    from lib import boto3
    File "/var/www/html/packages/lib/boto3/__init__.py", line 16, in 
    <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
```

but when i try to place this file(read.py) in lib folder then its import boto3 without an error why?

after place read.py file in lib

```
 Project 
 --> lib 
     --> boto3 package
     --> __init__.py
     --> read.py
 --> python script
```

Comment: is `/var/www/html/packages/lib/` added to PYTHONPATH so it can be imported?

Comment: No i did not add in PYTHONPATH this

Comment: How can i use this without PYTHONPATH ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add path in your PYTHONPATH

```
import os
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

user_home = os.environ["HOME"]
os.environ["PYTHONPATH"] = path+'/lib'
import sys
sys.path.append( path+'/lib')
import boto3
```